# HTML Canvas "getContext" of null error in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html5-canvas, tensorflow.js

I am constantly getting this
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`
in react.js while working with HTML canvas. the error is on line 27, i was converting code from .html file and i changed `document.getelementbyid("canvas") to canvasRef = useRef(null)` and then passed that into a function.

here's the code:

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import * as tmPose from '@teachablemachine/pose';

const URL = 'https://my_url';
let model, webcam, ctx, maxPredictions;

export default function App() {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    
    const runPosenet = async (canvas) => {
        const modelURL = URL + 'model.json';
        const metadataURL = URL + 'metadata.json'

        model = await tmPose.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

        ctx = canvas.current.getContext('2d');
        canvas.current.width = 640;
        canvas.current.height = 480;
        
    }
}

    runPosenet(canvasRef);


    return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <canvas ref = {canvasRef}/>
      </header>
      </div>
    );

}
```

how can i solve this error ?

Comment: You have a typo `<canva ref = {canvasRef}/>`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it.

Comment: @PsyGik Still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `runPosenet(canvasRef);` runs before the `render`, and the `canvas` is not on the DOM.

Put it in a `React.useEffect`.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    runPosenet(canvasRef);
  }, []); // <= Runs once on component load
```

Comment: Ohh..! Got it, Thanks a lot..! @PsyGik